# Suppress groups when page count exceeds 1

Tags: crystal-reports

I have an invoice that is sent annually to thousands of owners. Transactions are grouped by contract and then again by Owner#, meaning there can be multiple contracts for one Owner#. There is a PageNofM in the footer that resets on the change of Owner# grouping.

Our mailing company will only accept invoices that are the same for each recipient. So we remove all the multi-page invoices manually. I would like to output the single page invoices first and then the multi-page invoices.

I have been racking my brain trying to get this to work. I have tried suppressing based on totalpagecount>1 and Googled it in as many different ways I can come up with. So now I'm coming to the experts with my first post. Any thoughts?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: As far as i thought i understood, it should work just using the "totalpagecount>1" in the group section suppress formula. May you post a print screen of your layout?